# Display the number of results of a sql query

Tags: php, sql

I want to count number of rows for each value displayed from a joined table

2 tables (events and locations)

I want to count events (table events) for each location.Name (table locations)

```
        $resultN = doQuery("SELECT e.PkID 
                    FROM " . HC_TblPrefix . "events e 
                            LEFT JOIN " . HC_TblPrefix . "locations l ON (e.LocID = l.PkID)
                    WHERE DATE(StartDate) > DATE(CURDATE())
                    ");
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: So, what have you tried? And what is `doQuery`?

Comment: i tried to display with mysql_num_rows($resultN)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this query below to count the number of results where

```
SELECT l.name ,Count(e.PkID) 
FROM " . HC_TblPrefix . "events e 
LEFT JOIN " . HC_TblPrefix . "locations l ON (e.LocID = l.PkID)
WHERE DATE(StartDate) > DATE(CURDATE())
GROUP BY l.name
```

Result from this query will be like this

Location | Count

Madrid      6

Seattle     91

Comment: How to display results for each l.name ?

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
SELECT COUNT(*), l.name from events AS e
    JOIN locations AS l ON e.locid = l.locid
    WHERE DATE(startdate) > DATE(CURDATE())
    group by l.name
```

Comment: How to display results for each l.name ?

Comment: the query above will group results for each l.name and corresponding count.